# Meteor on Windows Localhost loading error

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor in windows 8(64 bit) and created the sample project on meteor by:
meteor create "hellowmeteor", then when I do cd hellometeor and meteor then there appears message on the cmd prompt.Meteor server running on :`http://localhost:3030` now when I go to the browser and type `http://localhost:3030` there is problem loading error. What is wrong with it ??
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you give more information? What is the version of Meteor, how did you get it? Did you use one of the solutions from win.meteor.com?

Comment: yup i downloaded from wim.meteor...btw i have fix my issue. i have to use port 3000 instead of 3030.